# Can continuous functions on Tychonoff spaces tell missing limit points apart?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a Tychonoff space. Let $\{x_i\}$ and $\{y_i\}$ be nets that don’t necessarily converge in $X$, but for every continuous function $f:X\rightarrow [0,1]$, $\{f(x_i)\}\rightarrow a_f\in \mathbb{R}$ and  $\{f(y_i)\}\rightarrow b_f\in \mathbb{R}$. If the two nets are eventually ‘outside’ each other, is the existence of an f such that $a_f\neq b_f$ guaranteed?

Comment: What precisely do you mean by the nets eventually being "outside" each other?  For instance, if you let $X = \mathbb{R}$, $x_n = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{n}$, $y_n = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{n}$, then your condition should exclude this case since for any continuous $f$, $f(x_n) \to f(\frac{1}{2})$ and $f(y_n) \to f(\frac{1}{2})$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mu$ and $\nu$ be the nets in question; I find it a bit easier to work with filters than with nets, so let $\mathscr{F}$ and $\mathscr{G}$ be the corresponding filters on $X$. $\mathscr{F}$ and $\mathscr{G}$ are filter bases on $\beta X$, so they can be extended to ultrafilters $\mathscr{U}$ and $\mathscr{V}$, respectively, on $\beta X$. Your condition separating the nets presumably implies that there are $F\in\mathscr{F}$ and $G\in\mathscr{G}$ such that $F\cap G=\varnothing$, so $\mathscr{U}\ne\mathscr{V}$. $\beta X$ is compact, so $\mathscr{U}$ and $\mathscr{V}$ converge to distinct points $p$ and $q$, respectively, in $\beta X$.

If $f:X\to[0,1]$ is continuous, and $\beta f$ is its unique continuous extension to $\beta X$, then $a_f=(\beta f)(p)$ and $b_f=(\beta f)(q)$. $\beta X$ is Tikhonov, so there is a continuous $g:\beta X\to[0,1]$ such that $g(p)=0$ and $g(q)=1$, and if we set $f=g\upharpoonright X$, then $a_f\ne b_f$.

Comment: Perfect. This question actually came from me struggling with the uniqueness concept of $\beta X$ (See my history if you’re interested) and this should clear it up!

Comment: @SchroedersCat: Excellent!

Comment: I don't see how you conclude that the ultrafilters converge to distinct points.  For instance, if you take my example under the question, then the images of $x_n$ and $y_n$ are disjoint but any ultrafilters extending the tail filter must contain these respective sets, but those ultrafilters must also both converge to $\frac{1}{2}$ in $[0,1] = \beta[0,1]$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler: The OP didn’t specify exactly what was meant by the nets eventually being outside each other (which is why I wrote *presumably*), but I think it a safe bet that it excludes your example.

Comment: @DanielSchepler I guess I was trying to enforce that if their limit points were in $X$, they would be topologically distinct. My make shift terminology doesn’t work though thanks to your example above.